# Formatting output of token

Tags: commerce, datetime, tokens

I have Drupal Commerce, and it sends confirmation emails after product is sold. In those emails are tokens. I have token `[commerce-order:created]` and I'm interested if is there any conveniant way to change a formatting of that date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `[commerce-order:created]` is a date token, then you can use `[commerce-order:created:custom:<the format you want to apply>]`, where `<the format you want to apply>` is the string format accepted by [`date()`](http://php.net/date).

Otherwise, the more generic way to alter tokens implemented by other modules is implementing [`hook_tokens_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_tokens_alter/7).

```
function mymodule_tokens_alter(&$replacements, $context) {
  $options = $context['options'];

  $sanitize = !empty($options['sanitize']);
  $langcode = !empty($options['language']->language) ? $options['language']->language : NULL;

  if ($context['type'] == 'commerce-order') {
    foreach ($context['tokens'] as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'created':
          // Set a value for $sanitized and $new_value.
          $replacements[$original] = $sanitize ? $sanitized : $new_value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that in my code:

- `$sanitized` is the sanitized value to assign to the token, used only when `$sanitize` is `TRUE`
- `$new_value` is the new value for the token, used to obtain the value of `$sanitized`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [hook_tokens_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_tokens_alter/7)

> Alter replacement values for placeholder tokens.

Eg:

```
/**
* Implements hook_tokens_alter().
*/
function mymodule_tokens_alter(&$replacements,  $context){
  // May be you can do some more ifs to reduce the load :)
  if(isset($replacements['[commerce-order:created]'])){
    $replacements['[commerce-order:created]']  = check_plain('YOUR-CUSTOM-REPLACEMENT');
  }

}
```