# Search API Saved Search tokens output [search-api-saved-search-result:url] has cron.php in urls

Tags: 7, search

I'm using Drupal 7 : with Search API

In this I'm using the token [search-api-saved-search-result:url] which I take it should output the Url of the relevant nodes.  The Urls are correct except the have 'cron.php' text in them .  ie 'www.example.com/cron.php/node/1234' ; making them not work.

this is the code in the Search API module.

```
case 'search-api-saved-search-result':
  $d = $data['search_api_saved_search_result_info'];
  if (!empty($d['search']) && !empty($d['entity'])) {
    $search = $d['search'];
    $index = $search->index();
    $item = $d['entity'];
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      if ($name == 'id' && ($id = $index->datasource()->getItemId($item))) {
        $replacements[$original] = $id;
      }
      elseif ($name == 'label' && ($label = $index->datasource()->getItemLabel($item))) {
        $replacements[$original] = $label;
      }
      elseif ($name == 'url' && ($url = $index->datasource()->getItemUrl($item))) {
        $url['options'] += $url_options;
       $replacements[$original] = url($url['path'], $url['options']); // $replacements[$original] = url('http://www.rcnbulletins.com/', $url['options']);
      }
    }
    if (($url_tokens = token_find_with_prefix($tokens, 'url')) && ($url = $index->datasource()->getItemUrl($item))) {
      $replacements += token_generate('url', $url_tokens, $url, $options);
              }
  }
  break;
```

I'm wondering if this is a bug or something i've missed in admin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution .  thanks to these answers [Formatting output of token](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86136/formatting-output-of-token/86143#86143)

```
/**
* Implements hook_tokens_alter().
*/
function rcn_tokens_alter(&$replacements,  $context){
  // fix urls being outputted with cron.php in the link.
  if(isset($replacements['[search-api-saved-search-result:url]'])){
  $url = $replacements['[search-api-saved-search-result:url]'];
  $newurl = str_replace("cron.php/", "", $url);
  $replacements['[search-api-saved-search-result:url]']  =   check_plain($newurl);
  }

}
```